# Extract the pose of an e57 file

Tags: pdal

I want to use pdal to extract the pose of each scan in one e57 file. However, I could not find any available way with the current pdal c++ API to do that. I can only get the coordinates and rgb information of the points. Is there any way to obtain the pose information with pdal?